# What's wrong in this queue implementation?

Tags: c, pointers, queue

following is my queue implementation. My queue is simply an array of two qnodes: head and rear. enqueue and dequeue are supposed to handle the internal queue implementation.

The output to `Q[0].next == Q[1].next` is coming 1 after I call enqueue with different integers. I am unable to figure out the mistake.

```
struct Qnode{
int index;
struct Qnode *next;
};
typedef struct Qnode qnode;

qnode* makeQueue(){
     qnode *Q;
     Q = (qnode *) malloc(2*sizeof(qnode));
     qnode head,tail;
     head.next = NULL;
     tail.next = NULL;
     head.index = 0;
     tail.index = -1;
     Q[0] = head;
     Q[1] = tail;
     return Q;
}

void enQueue(qnode *Q, int index){
    qnode node,head = Q[0], rear = Q[1];
    node.index = index;
    node.next = NULL;
    if(head.next == NULL && rear.next == NULL){
        head.next = &node;
        rear.next = &node;
    }
    else{
        (rear.next)->next = &node;
        rear.next = &node;
    }
    Q[0].index = head.index + 1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `malloc(2*sizeof(qnode));` ?

Comment: as Q itself will be an array of 2 qnodes

Comment: First, it won't be an *array* of 2 nodes, it will be a *linked list*, and you only need the head node to point to the first node or `NULL`. Your `enqueue` function should allocate the nodes as needed. [Example](https://gist.github.com/mycodeschool/7510222).

Comment: If after `makeQueue` you call `enQueue`, `(rear.next)->next = &node;` is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to `rear.next == -1`

Comment: I need two nodes as I want to keep track of the rear node too to have O(1) enqueue and dequeue operations. Secondly, is there any issue with using 2 element array? will a linked list be more efficient for storing just 2 nodes?

Comment: @LPs after makeQueue, head.next and rear.next will be pointing to NULL. so it will go in the if conditional in enQueue, so will not call (rear.next)->next. Am I missing something?

Comment: My bad. I misread the code.

Comment: oh. Can you suggest something? thanks!

Comment: You are copying the value of Q[0] into head variable and then modifying the value of that variable. This will not be reflected in Q[0]. You should either use a pointer *head into Q[0] or simply just use it as Q[0].whatever

Comment: Also you are doing stuff with the address of node, which is a local variable of enQueue method. After the method exits, it is gone!!! And the address is just useless.

Comment: @SelçukCihan Thank you. I changed that in the end just to make it look better. Should have figured that out.

Comment: @LPs Your below answer was the second issue with the code. Thanks

Comment: @SelçukCihan Can you put it as an answer so that I be able to mark it correct. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem into `enQueue` function

```
qnode node,head = Q[0], rear = Q[1];
node.index = index;
node.next = NULL;
if(head.next == NULL && rear.next == NULL){
    head.next = &node;
    rear.next = &node;
}
```

The piece of code above is assigning to `head.next` and `rear.next` the address of a local scoped variable: i.e. stack allocated variable.

`node` variable will only exists until the function ends. So the address into those pointers aren't valid outside the function: accessing it outside function is illegal and [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Moreover all modifications done into that function are not reflected to `Q` array: you are modifying local scoped copy of array elements.

Comment: Oh I see. I tried changing node to a qnode* node. The problem still remains

Comment: You should re-think all your code. That way is wrong and not what you need. You have to (I guess) implement a linked list, not an array of 2 elements that hold data.

Comment: I think the second problem was that I was making changes on head and rear which are local variables. The code works now. Thanks